# How to check current route in Iron Router Meteor

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router

I'm setting up a body helper for use with Iron Router to use as `{{route}}`:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  route: function(){
    alert(Router.current().route.getName());
  }
});
```

But `Router.current().route.getName()` returns undefined instead of "/thirdPage/".

Comment: replaced
Router.current().route.getName()
with
Router.current().route._path

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try:

```
Router.current().route.path()
```

Comment: first one returns "secondPage" and second returns "/secondPage" - the second is what I have been looking for, Thanks

Comment: Use the public method instead of the private attribute : `Router.current().route.path()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
Router.current().route.path()
```

Works fine until you have routes with parameters, at which point it suddenly retuns

```
null
```

making it pretty unreliable in my opinion.

```
Iron.Location.get().path
```

Seems to be the most reliable method at the moment for getting your path with parameters (not the complete url including "http://" as Router.current().url does)

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
Router.current().url
```

This gets whatever is in your url bar,
FYI

```
Router.current().params.yourParamName
```

This will get the content of your parameter